# GroupBy query selecting Last item

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

There is a job and part number that will have multiple operations assigned to it, and I am attempting to find the last operation of the job and only write that to the file.

```
using (var contextDb = new TimoToolEntities())
{
    using (var writeFile = new StreamWriter(saveTo))
    {

        var randomData = contextDb.WorkCenter_Operations
            .OrderBy(j => j.Job_Number)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Part_Number).
             ThenByDescending(o => o.Oper_Number)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                PartNumber = s.Part_Number,
                JobNumber = s.Job_Number,
                OpNumber = s.Oper_Number,
                OpDesc = s.Oper_Description,
                PlanComp = s.Planned_Complete

            }).GroupBy(c => new 
            {
                c.JobNumber,
                c.PartNumber,
                c.OpNumber,
                c.OpDesc,
                c.PlanComp

            });

        foreach (var record in randomData)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
                "Job Number: {0} Part Number: {1} Op Number: {2} Op Desc: {3} Plan Complete: {4}\n", 
                record.Key.JobNumber, 
                record.Key.PartNumber, 
                record.Key.OpNumber, 
                record.Key.OpDesc,
                record.Key.PlanComp)); 
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use Last(), LastorDefault() and even Max() (As the operation number increases until the job is finished) but wherever I put the call the next function says that a definition for it is not contained. How can I select the last operation and the data that goes along with it?

Comment: Try this... `contextDb.WorkCenter_Operations.OrderByDescending(j => j.Job_Number).ThenByDescending(p => p.Part_Number).
                     ThenByDescending(o => o.Oper_Number).Take(1);` You might have to fix the order as You better now which sort will bring the last job on top of the list.

Comment: The idea in above stated code snippet is to sort in reverse order and take the top 1.

Comment: I think your problem is that there is no SQL translation for `.Last()`
Above comment seems the way to go

Comment: @vendettamit sort in reverse and take first is probably best answer, this is simply because there's no sql equivalent of last, but there is a sql equivalent of Take(1) (being select top 1)

Comment: alternatively if you know the count, you could do .Skip(length - 1).Take(1) but this is likely going to be two calls, one to get the count and one to get the last

Comment: That works for one group. But I am trying to take the last op for each job and there are a number of them. Any way that could be done? @vendettamit

Comment: @Joe_DM the count of operations for each job is different so the skip method won't work

Comment: you should be able to sort within each group after the GroupBy

Comment: sorry, i notice you are doing a select where you new up an anonymous object, you might want to do the groupby first, then sort it, then select to first from each group

Comment: FYI, you don't have to use a `string.Format` inside of a `Console.WriteLine` because it can take the same arguments and do the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the last one for each job and part number then first group then select the one with the highest op number in each group by ordering on the op number and taking the first.

```
var lastOnes = contextDb.WorkCenter_Operations
    .GroupBy(o => new { o.Job_Number, o.Part_Number })
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(o => o.Oper_Number).First());
```

Comment: doing a `.First()` on the end will result in only the first group. Op wants the first item from each of the groups.

Comment: @Joe_DM The `First` is on the lambda inside of the `Select` not after it.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your data in reverse order and take the top 1. Do grouping first then sort and take top 1 by ordering in reverse order.

Below snippet shows the demonstration of how it can be done using LINQ.

```
 var randomData = contextDb.WorkCenter_Operations
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        PartNumber = s.Part_Number,
                        JobNumber = s.Job_Number,
                        OpNumber = s.Oper_Number,
                        OpDesc = s.Oper_Description,
                        PlanComp = s.Planned_Complete

                    }).GroupBy(s => s).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());

foreach (var record in randomData)
{
    var rec = record.OrderBy(j => j.JobNumber).ThenBy(p => p.PartNumber).
                     ThenByDescending(o => o.OperNumber).Take(1);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Job Number: {0} Part Number: {1} Op Number: {2} Op Desc: {3} Plan Complete: {4}\n", rec.JobNumber, rec.PartNumber, record.OpNumber, rec.OpDesc, rec.PlanComp));
}
```

You may have to define the grouping key based on your data.

Comment: This answer will enumerate the `IQueryable` before you finish defining the full query, As a result you're going to pull back the whole dataset from the database, at which point you may as well just do a `.Last()` since you're playing with Linq to Object instead of Linq to EntityFramework at that point.
edit for clairty: 
foreach (var record in randomData) will invoke the IQueryable which at the point it's invoked, will retrieve the whole table from the database.

Comment: I am getting this error in the writeline message 'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string PartNumber, decimal JobNumber, decimal OpNumber, string OpDesc, DateTime? PlanComp>>' does not contain a definition for 'JobNumber' and no extension method 'JobNumber' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string PartNumber, decimal JobNumber, decimal OpNumber, string OpDesc, DateTime? PlanComp>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Joe_DM I agree.. added ToDictionary() to yield data in memory.

Comment: @Max_P it's hard to write code on the fly like this without access to the context, You might have to make some tweaks to make it compile.
Just watch out if you go this route for database performance. Especially if it's small now, but will grow over time.

Comment: @Max_P you might have to update the `foreach` loop if you are going to use 'ToDictionary()`. Hope you get the gist how to proceed.

Comment: @vendettamit without knowing the ops data it's hard to say if this is okay. For example, if it's a small dataset that is constantly truncated or isn't increasing over time then it's probably okay. But if it's a list of all jobs in all of history, it can quickly get very large and start becoming slow or having out of memory issues.